# New Thread with INotifypropertyChanged or ObservableObject for uptade the View dont work in WinUi 3

Tags: c#

When I execute the **updateScreen()** function, an exception is thrown when the new value is set in the TextLabel string. This exception is demonstrated in the figure right after the code.

This error occurs when I invoke the screen update through the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface or through the method of the **ObservableObject** class, after creating a new Thread.

**My code:**

```
public class PageInicialViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int cont = 0;
    private string _textLabel = 0.ToString();
    public string TextLabel
    {
        get => _textLabel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _textLabel, value);
    }

    public void  updateScreen()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(updateTextLabel);
    }

    public void updateTextLabel()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cont++;
            TextLabel = cont.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }        
    }
}
```

**The Error:**
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

Comment: juwens explains exactly about your error, but I just want to mention that you should avoid using ``StartNew()``. You can find a good explanation [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). In your case, a ``PeriodicTimer`` might suit better.

Answer (score 2):

It's the age-old problem that the UI can only be updated from the main-thread (it was created with). (By varying degree of tolerance in one or other ui framework.)

Solution for WinUI would look something like this.

```
public class PageInicialViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int cont = 0;
    private string _textLabel = 0.ToString();
    private Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue _dispatcherQueue;

    public PageInicialViewModel()
    {
        // must be called on ui thread
        _dispatcherQueue = Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread(); 
    }    

    public string TextLabel
    {
        get => _textLabel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _textLabel, value);
    }

    public void  updateScreen()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(updateTextLabel);
    }

    public void updateTextLabel()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cont++;
            _dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
            {
                TextLabel = cont.ToString();
            });
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }        
    }
}
```

Just for reference, in WPF the same is achieved with:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{

});
```

You can find a lot of explanation and articles for the general technical principle of dispatching ui-changes to the ui-thread if you search for these term “Dispatcher.Invoke”.
The principle is the same, no matter if it’s WPF, WinForms, UWP, WinUI.

For example:

https://youtu.be/S0jPzb9kk3o?si=fms0hlDST7Mgt9fp